# Uniform integrability of $\sqrt{n} Y_n$ for $Y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-limit-theorems, uniform-integrability

Let $Y_n \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$.

Then the set $\{\sqrt{n} Y_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is uniformly integrable since

$$
\sqrt{n} Y_n \sim \sqrt{n}\mathcal{N}\bigg(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\bigg) = \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2),
$$
is a normal distribution that is not dependent on $n$.

Now suppose instead $Y_n$ is not normally distributed, but it is asymptotically normally distributed, i.e., $Y_n \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$. For example $Y_n$ could be the sample mean for $n$ iid observations.

Once again, consider the set $\{\sqrt{n} Y_n\}_{n \ge 1}$. Is it still uniformly integrable now that $Y_n$ is only asymptotically distributed as $\mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$?

If it isn't, are there additional assumptions that can be placed on $Y_n$ so that $\{\sqrt{n} Y_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ becomes uniformly integrable?

Comment: The mean of $\sqrt n Y_n$ is $\sqrt n \mu$. $\sqrt n  Y_n$ is not uniformly integrable even when $Y_n \sim N(\mu,\frac {\sigma^{2}} n)$ unless $\mu=0$.

Comment: Ok, we can take $\mu = 0$. I will edit the post.

Comment: The answer to your first question is no: for example, if you let any of the $Y_n$ be Cauchy distributed, then your family of r.v. won't be uniformly integrable. A sufficient condition for any family $\left(Z_i\right)_{i\in I}$ to be uniformly integrable is to have $\mathbb{E}|Z_i|^\alpha \leq C$ for all $i\in  I$ and some $\alpha>1$. If you are willing to make this kind of assumption (for example, if your sequence also converges in $L^2$) then you can recover uniform integrability.

Comment: But the Cauchy case is ruled out since it is asymptotic normality doesn't apply. We only have asymptotic normality for iid random variables with finite mean and variance, but the mean and variance of a Cauchy r.v. is undefined.

Comment: One of them could be Cauchy and the sequence could still converge to a normal distribution. You didn't mention that the $Y$s should be iid.

Answer (score 1):

Here we interpret the notation $Y_n \stackrel{a}{\sim} \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ as there exists  sequences of random variables $(\varepsilon_n)$ and $(Z_n)$ such that $\varepsilon_n\to 0$ in probability, $Z_n\sim \mathcal{N}(0, \frac{\sigma^2}{n})$ and $Y_n=Z_n+\varepsilon_n$. Then uniform integrability of $\{\sqrt{n} Y_n\}_{n \ge 1}$ is equivalent to the uniform integrability of $\{\sqrt{n} \varepsilon_n\}_{n \ge 1}$, but it does not need to hold. For example, $\varepsilon_n$ could take the value $n$ with probability $1/n$ and $0$ with probability $1-1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Any sequence of random variables with bounded second moments is uniformly integrable.